# ASP.NET MVC passing query result from controller to view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How to print the result of query in View page for ASP.NET MVC?
My code is:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
            var list = from m in db.MenuTables
                       select m.MenuName;

            return View(list);
        }
```

Now what should i write to print the result of this query in View Page?

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I would get in the habit of having `ViewModels` and then strongly typing your View, to that model.

The `model` will expose ONLY THE DATA you want to display. Nothing more, nothing less. So let's assume you want to display the Name, Price and some other meta data.

Pseudo-code:

```
//View Model
public class MenuItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public bool IsVegetarian { get; set; ]
}

public class IndexViewModel
{
    public IList<MenuItem> MenuItems { get; set; }
    public string MaybeSomeMessage { get; set; }
}

//in Controller
public ActionResult Index()
{
    // This gets the menu items from your db, or cache or whatever.
    var menuItemsFromDb = GetMenuItems(); 


    // Let's start populating the view model.
    IndexViewModel model = new IndexViewModel();    

    // Project the results to your model.
    IList<MenuItems> menuItems = null;
    if (menuItemsFromDb != null)
    {
        model.MenuItems = (from menuItem in menuItemsFromDb
                           select new MenuItem() {
                               Name = menuItem.Name,
                               Price = menuItem.Price,
                               IsVegetarian = menuItem.IsVegetarian
                           }).ToList();
    }
  
    // Anything else...
    model.MaybeSomeMessage = "Hi There!";

    return View(model);
}

//in View
@model IndexViewModel

<h3>@Model.MaybeSomeMessage</h3>
<ul>
    @foreach(var item in Model.MenuItems)
    {
        <li><a href="#">@item.Name</a> - $ @item.Price</li>
    }
</ul>
```

etc..

Note I've skipped some error checking, etc.

The point: only pass what you need.

At first, you may think this is much more code than is necessary. The best answer I can suggest to that thought, is that in the long run, you'll thank yourself for getting in the habit of this because the view should only ever know about the *exact* data it requires.

Nothing more, nothing less. Sending the least amount of data means you have a very light and simple view which will make your support/debugging much better. Next, you'll be able to unit test your controllers with a lot more intelligence and smarts, when you get to that.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `list` is an `IEnumerable` of strings (i.e. that MenuName is a string).

In your view, accept the model `IEnumerable<string>`

```
@model IEnumerable<string>
```

and then enumerate it

```
@foreach( string s in Model )
{
 <div>
  @s
 </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you want to do is call ToList() or else you could possibly be executing the same SQL query multiple times.

```
   public ActionResult Index()
   { 
        var list = (from m in db.MenuTables
                   select m.MenuName).ToList();

        return View(list);
    }
```

Secondly, I wouldn't just pass up a full list like that. You should create a ViewModel. That will allow you to pass up more data later on with a smaller effort.

```
     public ActionResult Index()
     {
        var model = new IndexModel();
        model.Tables = db.MenuTables.ToList();
        model.AnotherValue = "MENUS";

        return View(model);
     }
```

Now we are on the view, you will need to set the model and iterate the table.

```
 @model IndexModel

 <h3>@Model.AnotherValue</h3>
 <ul>
 @foreach( var table in Model.Tables) {
     <li>@table.Name<li>
 }
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var list = from m in db.MenuTables
                   select m.MenuName;

        return View(list);
    }

    //In View

    @model IEnumerable<ProjectName.models.MenuTables>

    @foreach(var item in Model)
    { 
        @item.Field_Name
    }
```